# Type unsafe code (intentionally), and signed > unsigned > signed arithmetic

Tags: c, unsigned, void-pointers, signed

I am attempting to benchmark some different algorithm designs, and I would like to generalize my functions by making them type unsafe internally with user-enforced type safety.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void * foo1(unsigned n)
{
    unsigned i;
    unsigned long sum = 0;
    void * psum = &sum;

    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        ++sum;

    return psum;
}

...

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    unsigned n;
    unsigned long sum = 0;
    void *(*foo[6])(unsigned) = {&foo1, &foo2, &foo3, &foo4, &foo5, &foo6};
    unsigned n_max[6] = {1000000001, 1000001, 10001, 1000001, 101, 1001};
    clock_t start, end;

    for(i = 0; i < 6; ++i){
        n = 1;
        do{
            start = clock();
            sum = *(unsigned long *)(*foo[i])(n);
            end = clock();
            printf("%d|%lu|%.6f\n", n, sum, (double) (end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
            n *= 10;
        }while(n < n_max[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My question specifically is about how I might make my foo() functions more generic than they are, enabling me to use them for every type.

To that end, I had an idea, but I'm not sure about it; if a signed data type is cast to unsigned, then modified by any sort of other unsigned data type, will the arithmetic performed stick, or will erroneous math happen?

Comment: You're always casting the result of the function pointers to an `unsigned long*` and then de-referencing it. So why not have it just return an `unsigned long`?  I guess I don't understand what you're trying to do exactly.

Comment: The purpose is:
"make my foo() functions more generic than they are, enabling me to use them for every type"
What I'm doing on that line you're referencing is type casting the void pointer which is required in order to allow a return type of "anything."